# How to limit the checked checkboxes to just one at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to create a filter using checkboxes. I need to only have one checkbox checked at a time. How do I do this?

Scenario: The page has a catalog of watches. The user wants to filter the watches according to for men or for women

Here is my code:

```js
$("#filter-options :checkbox").click(function() 
 {
        $(".collection-wrapper .strap-wrapper").hide();
        $("#filter-options :checkbox:checked").each(function() 
        {
           $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
  });
       
        if($('#filter-options :checkbox').filter(':checked').length < 1) 
        {
         $(".collection-wrapper .strap-wrapper").fadeIn();
         
        }
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Filter Items</h3>
<ul id="filter-options">
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_man" data-filter_id="man"> Man</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_woman" data-filter_id="woman"> Woman</li>
</ul>


<div class="collection-wrapper">
  <div class="strap-wrapper filter_man">
    <h2>man</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="strap-wrapper filter_woman">
    <h2>woman</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="strap-wrapper filter_man filter_woman">
    <h2>man / woman</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="strap-wrapper filter_woman">
    <h2>woman</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thought about radiobuttons? As these have exactly the functionality you want? Link: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Checkboxes** are used for selecting multiple values of choices. What you need is **Radio Buttons**. They are used exactly for this purpose. One can select only one radio button at a time. So replace your code with:

```
<ul id="filter-options">
  <li><input type="radio" name="filter" value="filter_man" data-filter_id="man"> Man</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="filter" value="filter_woman" data-filter_id="woman"> Woman</li>
</ul>
```

**See an example here:** http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are what you are looking for ;)

take at look at these links:

[jQuery api demo](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/MsYqx/)

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name="myRadio"]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use radio buttons or you could do something like:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 1) {
        this.checked = false;
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use radio buttons, but if you want to do it with checkboxes, solution is pretty simple.

When you click on one of the checkboxes, select all the checkboxes and remove "checked" state, and then just add checked on clicked checkbox

Something like this:

```
    // On checkbox click
    $("#filter-options input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {

        // Uncheck all checkboxes
        $("#filter-options input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);

        // Check that one that you clicked
        $(this).prop("checked", true)
    });
```